# Solace connectivity from VB 6.0

Tags: solace, solace-mq

What are the options available to connect to solace from VB 6.0? Is it possible to establish this connectivity using AMQP 1.0 protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Solace supports AMQP 1.0, MQTT 3.1.1 and REST.

You are free to use any third party libraries(or even write your own) that implements any of the above protocols to interact with a Solace message broker.